# Implementing an enqueue function for a Linked list class in C++

Tags: c++, class, pointers, linked-list, queue

Each node stores a pointer to an object of a data class so working with all the memory allocation and such is very confusing.

I Think the issue is the way the enqueue function was implemented or something wrong with the creation of a Node object or a creation of a Data object. Since im not to confident with pointers that could also be an issue since I could be assigning things improperly.

What ends up happening is the queue only gets one node in it after adding many nodes to the Queue. (its used in a grocery store simulation)

```
//Add data to front 
bool Queue::enqueue(Data newData) {
    return this->enqueue(this->pTail, newData);
}
bool Queue::enqueue(Node * pTail, Data newData) {
    //If queue is empty, head and tail point to the new Node
    Data * pData = new Data(newData);
    //Test if data was allocated to heap
    if (pData == nullptr) {
        return false;
    }
    //If empty
    if (pTail == nullptr) {
        pTail = new Node(pData);
        this->pHead = pTail;
    }
    //If queue isnt empty
    else {
        //Add new node to the old end, then set new end to new node
        pTail->setPNext(new Node(pData));
        pTail = pTail->getPNext();
    }
    return true;
}
```

Node Class

```
class Node {
private:
    Data * pData;    
    Node * pNext;
public:
    Node() {
        pNext = nullptr;
    }
    Node(Data * n) {
        pData = n;
        pNext = nullptr;
    }
    ~Node() {
    }
    //Setter
    void setPNext(Node * newPNext) {
        pNext = newPNext;
    }
    void setData(Data newData) {
        pData->setData(&newData);
    }
    //Getters here
```

Data Class

```
class Data {
private:
    int customerNumber;
    int serviceTime;   
    int totalTime;    
public: 
    Data() {
    }
    Data(int n, int s, int tPrev) {
        customerNumber = n;
        serviceTime = s;
        totalTime = tPrev;
    }
    Data(Data &d) {
        customerNumber = d.getCNum();
        serviceTime = d.getSTime();
        totalTime = d.getTotalTime();
    }
    Data &operator= (Data &d) {
        customerNumber = d.getCNum();
        serviceTime = d.getSTime();
        totalTime = d.getTotalTime();

        return *this;
    }
```

The implementation of the Queue class should be fine, so I wont include it here.

Within main, the Data point is created then added onto the queue

```
    //Create new customer data (ints)
    Data newData(newCustomerNumber, newExpressTime, totalExpressTime);

    //Add customer to queue
    express.enqueue(newData);
```

Comment: Does each node *have* to store a pointer? Just having a linked list means you already have a lot of pointers floating around. Could you not have the node directly contain a data object?

Comment: Not really either method should be fine but switching over to that still gives the error, so Its probably in the enqueue function where the error occurs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In

```
bool Queue::enqueue(Node * pTail, Data newData)
```

You have two variables named `pTail`. One is the member variable `Queue::pTail`, but this member is hidden ([Variable Shadowing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing)) by the local parameter `pTail`, a completely different variable, because the parameter `pTail` was defined in a closer scope.

The `Node` pointed at by the parameter `pTail` is passed by reference and is the same `Node` as `Queue::pTail` points to, but `pTail` itself is passed by value and is merely a copy of the address that is `Queue::pTail`'s value. This means when you repoint `pTail`, with

```
pTail = new Node(pData);
```

for example, `pTail` the copy is repointed. The original in the calling function is left unchanged.

Solution:

Pass the pointer by reference as well. Change

```
bool Queue::enqueue(Node * pTail, Data newData)
```

to

```
bool Queue::enqueue(Node *& pTail, Data newData)
```

Side notes:

```
Data * pData = new Data(newData);
if (pData == nullptr) {
    return false;
}
```

Doesn't do anything useful. The `Data` assigned to `pData` is never assigned to a variable with a longer scope, so it is leaked when the function exits. In addition, `new`'s default behaviour is to throw an exception when it fails rather than return `nullptr`. Since I don't see the default behaviour being replaced anywhere, I suspect that the test for `nullptr` will never be used.

`Queue::enqueue` should look more like

```
bool Queue::enqueue(Node *& pTail, Data newData) {
    if (pTail == nullptr) {
        pTail = new Node(pData);
        this->pHead = pTail;
    }
    else {
        pTail->setPNext(new Node(pData));
        pTail = pTail->getPNext();
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Wait but I want to modify the pTail using enqueue. If I pass by reference does it still modify the Tail stored in the Queue object?

Comment: If you pass by reference you modify `this->pTail`. If you pass by value, as you currently are, you do not modify `this->pTail`. Instead you modify a local copy.

Comment: @LouisPelletier Hopefully this edit describes what happened a bit better.